# show Customized QuickAction popup Window in android

Tags: android, popupwindow

i am trying to built the quick Action in my project. when i click the view it show the pop up window properly. But the arrow(arrow up, arrow down) which is point to the Parent View is not showing. i have tried it in many ways. if some one have the better solution or good logic please help me
thanks:
 Here you can see the code:

```
public void show (View anchor) {
        preShow();

        int[] location      = new int[2];

        anchor.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        Rect anchorRect     = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0] + anchor.getWidth(), location[1] 
                            + anchor.getHeight());

        mRootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(300, 400));
        mRootView.measure(200,300);

        int rootWidth       = mRootView.getMeasuredWidth();
        int rootHeight      = mRootView.getMeasuredHeight();

        int screenWidth     = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        int xPos            = (screenWidth - rootWidth) / 2;
        int yPos            = anchorRect.top - rootHeight;

        boolean onTop       = true;

        if (rootHeight > anchor.getTop()) {
            yPos    = anchorRect.bottom;
            onTop   = false;
        }
        if(onTop==true){
            showArrow(R.id.arrow_down, anchorRect.centerX());
        }
        else
        {
            showArrow( R.id.arrow_up, anchorRect.centerX());
        }
```

and showArrow method is as:

```
private void showArrow(int whichArrow, int requestedX) {
        final View showArrow;
        final View hideArrow;
        if(whichArrow==R.id.arrow_down)
        {
            showArrow=mArrowDown;
            hideArrow=mArrowUp;

        }
        else{
            showArrow=mArrowUp;
            hideArrow=mArrowDown;       
        }


        final int arrowWidth = mArrowUp.getMeasuredWidth();

        showArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams param = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)showArrow.getLayoutParams();

        param.leftMargin = requestedX - arrowWidth / 2;

        hideArrow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with you code.Probably,some thing will be wrong in your xml file. Please review you xml file. Try to modify you xml file. Hopefully,your problem will be resolved.